# How to set text from Firebase currentUser

Tags: android, firebase, textview

So I'm trying to set `TextView` with Firebase user's email, but I get the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: emailTV must not be null`

How to set Firebase user's email to this `TextView` ?

MainActivity.kt

```
val currentUser = auth.currentUser
if (currentUser != null) {
    navView.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_login).isVisible = false;
    emailTV.text = currentUser.email.toString()
}
```

nav_header_main.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emailTV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="Anonomys User"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not from Firebase, instead is that your `textView` is null, if you are using synthetics, make sure that you are importing the right textView

You can use a Log to see if you are getting the email

```
Log.d("Firebase_Email", currentUser.email.toString())
```

Comment: I'm getting the email, in Logcat I see my email

Comment: the problem is in the textView, maybe you are not calling the right one or initializing it right

Answer (score 0):

Set the text using:

```
val currentUser = auth.currentUser
if (currentUser != null) {
    navView.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_login).isVisible = false;
    emailTV.setText(currentUser.email.toString()).toString()  

}
```

[Kotlin TextView](https://www.javatpoint.com/kotlin-android-textview-and-edittext)